# Git and CMake project structure, external libraries and packages

Tags: git, cmake, libraries, project-structure

I'm relatively inexperienced with CMake projects and also with Git.

If I use external libraries, e.g. in my case JsonCpp and OpenVR, is it a bad approach to place the packages/libraries inside my project structure and push them with my own stuff to my Git repository?

The reason why I do that is because I want to make it easier for future users, so they do not have to download these libraries and add the install directory to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH themselves.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

> is it a bad approach to place the packages/libraries inside my project structure and push them with my own stuff to my Git repository?

Yes, it is.

> The reason why I do that is because I want to make it easier for future users, so they do not have to download these libraries and add the install directory to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH themselves.

You can do that only if you are sure that users will run them on the same OS/arch. If those libraries use some other system libraries, you also have to make sure that these are present on user system and have compliant versions.

This is pretty flaky in general, that's the common practice is to distribute dependencies separately and search for them during configuring stage.

Answer (score 2):

You need some dependency manager. For C++ [Conan](https://conan.io/) is quite nice. Or you can use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

`cmake` also has some solution for that [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html).

I never configured any of this, but I've been using Conan and Maven (someone else setup everything).

There are also other tools, you have to just pick one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go as far as saying that bundling dependencies with your project is bad practice full stop, nomatter what build system/generator you use. And as [**arrowd** already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58972697/9118298) you will then have to resolve your dependencies' dependencies which is a can of worms you don't want to open.

CMake in particular has pretty powerful dependency management system, via the [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command, as well as a powerful interface to [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) via [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPkgConfig.html) and [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPkgConfig.html)

During configuration, if a required dependency is not found , CMake will print a message which makes it clear which library is missing, and it is then up to the user to install this and resolve it however they please.

When it comes to finding these dependencies at link time, once again you don't need to worry about your users as CMake manages all of these for you.

I'd recommending watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk) on an insight of CMake, and then doing some research about using [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), and how to write your own Find modules if the ones you are using provide neither a Find module, nor a pkg-config file.